# Jboss AS 7.1 stuck on starting state

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have been practicing creating servlets and running it on Jboss AS 7.1, but whenever I start the JBoss server on eclipse, it just stays on the running state.

What could be done to fix this problem? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Here are some snippets of my configuration.

[Server Runtime Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvYuy.jpg)

[Server Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxrNS.jpg)

Here is the Console message.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

17:57:06,992 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA

17:57:07,129 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA

17:57:07,159 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem while using JBoss7.1.1Final App Server with java8 on linux,

After setting java 7 as default, 
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
and in bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

IT's Working fine